# Why does WIFEXITED return false after child process exits?

Tags: c, fork, wait

I've got this simple program that creates a child process which immediately calls `exit()`. So in the parent process I'm expecting `WIFEXITED(status)` to evaluate as `true`, but it's not. Instead, `WIFSTOPPED(status)` evaluates as `true` and "stopped" is printed. Can anyone explain why I'm getting this behavior? I'm running on OS X and compiling with gcc. Thanks!

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(void)
{
    int pid;
    int status;

    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0)
        printf("fork failed\n");
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        wait(&status);
        if (WIFEXITED(status))
            printf("exited\n");
        else if (WIFSTOPPED(status))
            printf("stopped\n");
    }
    else
        exit(0);

    return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the logic for the child and parent backwards. The parent is exiting immediately and the child is calling `wait`. Since the child has no children, `wait` is returning an error (and not touching `status`) since the child has no children (`ECHILD`), then you're testing the (uninitialized) value of `status` and acting on it, resulting in undefined behavior.

Change:

```
else if (pid == 0)
```

to:

```
else if (pid > 0)
```

and it should work as expected.